# Convert C# List of object to JavaScript array of objects

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI's [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) to allow the search of users. The documentation states that I am able to use an array for the source of the data in the following format: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

I have a base class that provides a list of unique `Users` which is inherited by my view-model. The view model has the following function:

```
public List<TestJson> GetUsers()
{
    return AvailableUsers
        .Select(u => new TestJson
            {
                Label = u.LastName + ", " + u.FirstName + "(" + u.UserId + ")",
                Value = u.UserId
            }).ToList();
}

public class TestJson
{
    public string Label { set; get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I use the above like so:

```
var userNameList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GetUsers()));

$("#UserName").autocomplete({
    source:userNameList 
});
```

Turns out `userNameList` is showing up like this:

```
[ { "Label": "Choice1", "Value": "value1" }, ... ]
```

instead of:

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

How can I get my array to show in the correct format?

**EDIT:** Based on input from comments, I have verified that both those formats are indeed functionally equivalent. I did a little more testing and it turns out that `label` and `value` are case sensitive. Changing my members to lower case seems to do the trick, but I don't feel that solution is the best. Any suggestions on how to change the string on the left side of the : (what is this called?) to lowercase?

Comment: Either of those outputs should work fine. What's the issue you're having?

Comment: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]` is functionally equivalent to `[ { "label": "Choice1", "value": "value1" }, ... ]`, or are you experiencing a problem?

Comment: @RobG You are right! Please see my edit

Comment: I was hit with the same. Just to get past this, I went with lower-cased properties. You might find an attribute decoration to control the name that's used during serialization but I don't see anything immediately available unless you're using the Newtonsoft library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing

Comment: After a deeper look, it seems MVC uses JavaScriptSerializer which doesn't respect [DataMember] attributes like JSON.NET does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497124/define-json-field-names-when-using-jsonresult so you can either switch to JSON.NET or look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302946/asp-net-mvc-controlling-serialization-of-property-names-with-jsonresult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments by Jason P and Rob G are correct. The two formats in questions are equivalent. Turns out my issue was with the casing. DOH!

I just changed the properties in my class to be lower case. Thought, I would love to see an alternate solution.  I will choose this one until a better one is submitted.

Comment: Came here to figure out how to convert a C# list of objects to a javascript array of objects -- your problem was my solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
        //View.cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrayOfArrays = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GetUsers()))');
</script>
```

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation so if it's a valid JavaScript object is there even a need to parse it? `var arrayOfArrays = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GetUsers());`

Answer (score 2):

A simple Employee object:

```
public class Employee
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Age { get; set; }
public string ID { get; set; }   
}
```

Adding some instances of them to a List:

```
Employee oEmployee1 = 
new Employee{Name="Pini",ID="111", Age="30"};

Employee oEmployee2 = 
new Employee { Name = "Yaniv", ID = "Cohen", Age = "31" };
Employee oEmployee3 = 
new Employee { Name = "Yoni", ID = "Biton", Age = "20" };

List<Employee> oList = new List<Employee>() 
{ oEmployee1, oEmployee2, oEmployee3 };
```

Serializing then:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
```

And here is the output:

```
[{"Name":"Pini","Age":"30","ID":"111"},
{"Name":"Yaniv","Age":"31","ID":"Cohen"},
{"Name":"Yoni","Age":"20","ID":"Biton"}]
```

Also below link has similar example

[Convert Object to JSON in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821078/convert-object-to-json-in-mvc-4)

Answer (score 1):

If you passing List of object though MVC model and want to store it an array variable in script section on .cshtml page PFB code snipt :-

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ListPropertyName))
```

Answer (score 1):

**As of .NET Core 3.0, it's simpler.**

Instead of doing this in your view:

```
var userNameList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.GetUsers()));
```

Do this:

```
var userNameList = @Json.Serialize(Model.GetUsers());
```

Note that:

1. Converting keys to *camelCase* is the default behavior.
2. The result type is `IHtmlContent`, which does not need to be wrapped inside `@Html.Raw()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using MVC. WebAPI will default to camelCase while MVC defaults to PascalCase.

See also: [Proper JSON serialization in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244774/proper-json-serialization-in-mvc-4) and http://www.matskarlsson.se/blog/serialize-net-objects-as-camelcase-json.